# My MVC Razor Data anotations and some razor helpers arent working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model, html-helper

My Data annotations and some helpers like @validationMessage  arent working, please help, it is on [required], [maxlength], etc.

```
this is my model:



this is my html helper 



   @Html.LabelFor(c => c.baseNumber)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.baseNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "7", pattern = "[0-9,.,-]+" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("baseNumber", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

my model

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Base number is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Base number")]
        [Range(1, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Value length must be of 7.")]



it doesnt work
```

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Script references in `_Layout.cshtml` and `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` support client-side validation.Here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0).You need to add `<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial">` to your view.:

```
    <form>
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.baseNumber)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.baseNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "7", pattern = "[0-9,.,-]+" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessage("baseNumber", new { @class = "text-danger" })                        
                           
                            
    </form>
@section Scripts{

<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial">
}
```

result:

[image]

Or you can copy the script references in `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`  to your view:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```